# Dokku app not deploying. Can anyone help me make sense of the logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, dokku

I've been struggling with deploying an app on Dokku since yesterday. I've been able to deploy two others on the same PaaS platform but for some reason, this one seems to be giving issues.

Right now, I can't even make sense of these logs.

```
11:30:52 rake.1    | started with pid 12
11:30:52 console.1 | started with pid 14
11:30:52 web.1     | started with pid 16
11:30:52 worker.1  | started with pid 18
11:31:30 worker.1  | [Worker(host:134474ed9b8c pid:18)] Starting job worker
11:31:30 worker.1  | 2015-09-21T11:31:30+0000:[Worker(host:134474ed9b8c pid:18)] Starting job worker
11:31:31 worker.1  |   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (9.8ms)      UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2015-09-21 11:31:31.090080', locked_by = 'host:134474ed9b8c pid:18' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2015-09-21     11:31:30.694648' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2015-09-21 07:31:30.694715') OR locked_by = 'host:134474ed9b8c pid:18') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
11:31:32 console.1 | Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.0)
11:31:33 web.1     | [2015-09-21 11:31:33] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
11:31:33 web.1     | [2015-09-21 11:31:33] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-linux]
11:31:33 web.1     | [2015-09-21 11:31:33] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=20 port=5200
11:31:33 rake.1    | Abort testing: Your Rails environment is running in production mode!
11:31:33 console.1 | Switch to inspect mode.
11:31:33 console.1 |
11:31:33 console.1 | exited with code 0
11:31:33 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
11:31:33 worker.1  | [Worker(host:134474ed9b8c pid:18)] Exiting...
11:31:33 worker.1  | 2015-09-21T11:31:33+0000: [Worker(host:134474ed9b8c pid:18)] Exiting...
11:31:33 rake.1    | exited with code 1
11:31:33 web.1     | terminated by SIGTERM
11:31:36 worker.1  |   SQL (1.6ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET "locked_by" = NULL, "locked_at" = NULL WHERE "delayed_jobs"."locked_by" = $1  [["locked_by", "host:134474ed9b8c pid:18"]]
11:31:36 worker.1  | exited with code 0
```

I really would appreciate if anyone could help catch what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What is the `rake` task in your Procfile? That seems to be executing on application start.

Comment: @JoseDiaz-Gonzalez The rake task in my procfile is `web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT` . Sorry I didn't get a notification when you commented. I don't understand which tasks are running all these delayed jobs in the logs. There's no trace of anything like that in development mode.

Comment: No, the `rake` task. That's the `web` task. Can you update your issue with the entire contents of your `Procfile`?

Comment: @JoseDiaz-Gonzalez That's the web task? that's the only line I have in my Procfile. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Where are you getting these logs from? Are you deploying this to dokku, as dokky logs don't even look like that.

Comment: The other thing is that the log output you listed definitely has `rake`, `console`, `web` and `worker` processes. Not really sure whats going on in your system. Perhaps you have a custom plugin installed that is running amok?

Comment: @JoseDiaz-Gonzalez sure these are dokku logs! I thought the command in my Procfile just started the server in the same way as me running `rails server -p 4000` would start the server on port 4000 in development mode. I got really confused when I saw `worker`s in the logs. I literarily was shocked and started googling stuff. I'm still yet to get any beam of light. Is there anything I can do to be more helpful?

Comment: We can probably help you quicker on irc. If you cannot use that, can you paste the output of `ls -lah` in the base of your app's directory? And then also `cat Procfile`.